# Why incrementing in PHP Session not working

Tags: php, session

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['wylosowana'])) {
    $_SESSION['wylosowana'] = rand(1,100);
}

if(isset($_POST['liczba'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['proba'])) {
        $_SESSION['proba'] = 1;
    }

    if($_POST['liczba']<$_SESSION['wylosowana']) {
        $_SESSION['blad'] = "Wprowadzona liczba jest za mała";

        if(isset($_SESSION['proba'])) {
            $_SESSION['proba']=+1; 
        }

    } else if ($_POST['liczba']>$_SESSION['wylosowana']) {
        $_SESSION['blad'] =  "Wprowadzona liczba jest za duża";
        if(isset($_SESSION['proba'])) {
            $_SESSION['proba']=+1; 
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['zgadles']=true;
        $_SESSION['blad'] =  "Wygrałeś za ".$_SESSION['proba']." razem";
    }
}
```

`$_SESSION['proba']` always is equal to 1. To be honest i dont know where is the problem. I tried few methods but it still not working. Please tell me where is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `=+` is a typo, it should be `+=`. Voting to close as off-topic as a typo.

Comment: @Qirel Why not just post that as an answer?  It seems on-topic to me (it's a question about programming, on Stackoverflow), and the submitter shows their attempts to solve it.

Comment: @Brian because typo questions are defined as off-topic, (emphasis mine) "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*"

Answer (score 1):

Your code : `$_SESSION['proba']=+1;`

Use instead `$_SESSION['proba'] += 1;` or `$_SESSION['proba'] = $_SESSION['proba'] + 1;`